# Найти min и max в массивах. Из полученных min найти наименьший элемент

Tags: pascal

n - массивов, разной размерности, нужно найти `min` и `max` в этих массивах. Из полученных `min` найти наименьший элемент, из `max` наибольший.

Comment: что сделали, что не получается? что спрашиваете?

Comment: Как задать несколько массивов? Как осуществить поиск среди полученных min и max, наименьшего и наибольшего?

Comment: @dmkk: Зависит от диалекта паскаля, с которым вы работаете. Можно ли в вашем диалекте объявить массив массивов неодинаковой длины? (Под размерностью вы понимаете скорее всего длину, правильно?)

Comment: @VladD: Программа должна запрашивать у пользователя кол-во массивов, а потом длину каждого массива. Как это сделать?

Comment: @dmkk: А ваш диалект паскаля поддерживает динамические массивы (то есть массивы, размер которых не известен во время компиляции)?